# Why does getSignatureStatuses always return null?

Tags: transactions, jsonrpc-api

I want to build a nice ui that shows the current status of a transaction counting up the confirmations up to 31.

For some reason I am not getting a result. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

The json I am sending to the RPC.

> {"method":"getSignatureStatuses","params":[["3EKVxNaGsuZBm24Kb33exdbB3uy3XTGv5GbuLYhmmZifrQpEka3PEhNZs2m8gbLWBHo3TLMLsxM8QjabW3tuDkXs"]],"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0}

The result I am getting

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"context":{"apiVersion":"1.10.29","slot":141942914},"value":[null]},"id":0}

I can use getSignaturesForAddress, which works, but it seems a bit of a waste and does not show me the confirmations either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSignatureStatus(es)` only searches the so-called `StatusCache` by default.  This cache contains all processed transactions that have not yet been finalized.  This default behavior is intended to provided the quickest reply to the request.

The methods can [optionally request](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#parameters-29) that transaction "history" be searched, which will look in both the local ledger, and if available a deep ledger history store like BigTable.

Something like this should work, assuming the block including the transaction has not been pruned from the local ledger or deep history is available.

```
{
  "method":"getSignatureStatuses",
  "params":[
    [
      "3EKVxNaGsuZBm24Kb33exdbB3uy3XTGv5GbuLYhmmZifrQpEka3PEhNZs2m8gbLWBHo3TLMLsxM8QjabW3tuDkXs"
    ],
    {
      "searchTransactionHistory":true
    }
  ],
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":0
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, that was it. And confirmations is just not set when its already finalized thats why i always got that null pointer there :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# code to show progress of a transaction for who is interested in the the working result. It nicely counts up the confirmation until the transaction is finalized.

```
private async Task CheckSignatureStatus(string signature)
{
    NftService nftService = ServiceFactory.Instance.Resolve<NftService>();
    MessageRouter messageRouter = ServiceFactory.Instance.Resolve<MessageRouter>();

    bool transactionFinalized = false;

    while (!transactionFinalized)
    {
        RequestResult<ResponseValue<List<SignatureStatusInfo>>> signatureResult =
            await nftService.GarblesRpcClient.GetSignatureStatusesAsync(new List<string>() {signature}, true);

        if (signatureResult.Result == null)
        {
            messageRouter.RaiseMessage(new BlimpSystem.ShowBlimpMessage($"There is no transaction for Signature: {signature}."));
            return;
        }

        foreach (var signatureStatusInfo in signatureResult.Result.Value)
        {
            if (signatureStatusInfo == null)
            {
                messageRouter.RaiseMessage(
                    new BlimpSystem.ShowBlimpMessage("Signature is not yet processed. Retry in 2 seconds."));
            }
            else
            {
                if (signatureStatusInfo.ConfirmationStatus == nameof(TransactionResult.finalized))
                {
                    transactionFinalized = true;
                    messageRouter.RaiseMessage(new BlimpSystem.ShowBlimpMessage("Transaction finalized"));
                }
                else
                {
                    messageRouter.RaiseMessage(
                        new BlimpSystem.ShowBlimpMessage($"Signature result {signatureStatusInfo.Confirmations}/31"));
                }
            }
        }

        if (!transactionFinalized)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```