# When TransactionStatusMeta can be None?

Tags: rust, rpc, client

After calling `get_transaction` from [solana_client](https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/solana_client/rpc_client/struct.RpcClient.html#method.get_transaction) you get an `EncodedTransactionWithStatusMeta` which contains `meta: Option<UiTransactionStatusMeta>` field. However, docs do not say when `meta` can be `None`, so currently I'm simply using `unwrap` on it. Which doesn't seem to be ideal.

So the question is when can this field be `None` and how should I handle this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does getSignatureStatuses always return null?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/319/why-does-getsignaturestatuses-always-return-null)

Comment: This is a completely different question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from declaring **NOT** to include meta in `get_transaction`, here's why:

> TLDR: The archival storage that sits behind a node may not have it.

In Solana, nodes store historical information such as history blocks and transactions in its ledger (in the actual machine). When said machine's SSD capacity is no longer capable of storing the sheer amount of storage required for storing the upcoming block data, it stashes the oldest data elsewhere; For instance, Solana nodes generally store its historical information in Google BigTable.

When this happens, there are potential mishaps between the nodes and its off-node store (such as BigTable). Eventually, when a user calls a RPC node for `get_transaction`, the meta may not be included because it doesn't exist in the BigTable archive.

Potential reasons:

1. The off-node store at certain point in time may have failed to ingest the incoming data from the node. While the node dumps that piece of information away, the store fails to ingest the dumped information. Thus, both parties will lose it.
2. (May be wrong), but certain node hosting companies or teams choose not to archive the meta of a transaction.
3. Bug? (References point 1)